# How to implement a weak reference to an object in a constructor using boost::weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

How does one create a boost::weak_ptr to an exiting object in C++ inside a constructor?

Here's what I've got but it doesn't work because the shared pointer constructor is wrong. The thing is i don't want to make a new task. I want to use the task that is required to make a TestCallback but i only want a weak reference to the TestTask because the TestTask owns the TestCallback and if it goes away so should the TestCallback.

```
class TestCallback {
  public:
    TestCallback(TestTask task);
    boost::weak_ptr<TestTask> testTask;
};
```

//Constructor

```
TestCallback(TestTask task) {
  boost::shared_ptr<DeleteStaticRouteTask> sharedTask(task);
  boost::weak_ptr<DeleteStaticRouteTask> weakTask(sharedTask);
  m_task = weakTask;
}
```

//Ideal Call Site

```
TestTask testTask(DependencyA, DependencyB);
TestCallback testCallback(task);
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: i think you're right.

Comment: problem is that OP do not understand what `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` does so `enable_shared_from_this` will not help. Take a look how `task` is passed by value and local `shared_ptr` is created and then assigned to a `weak_ptr`. I recommend reading documentation and understand what those things do before using them. Here is great [cpp con lecture about topic](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE).

Comment: Marek, how is it that you know what i understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that one cannot instantiate an object with a weak pointer. Here's an example you can use to implement weak references between objects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class Callback;

class Task: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Task>
{
  public:
    Task(Callback& callback)
      : m_callback(callback)
    {
      std::cout << "Task:: Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    void delegateMethod() {
      std::cout << "Task: delegateMethod" << std::endl;
    }

  private:
    Callback& m_callback;
};


class Callback
{
  public:

    Callback(){
      std::cout << "Callback::Constructor" << std::endl;
    };

    //You have to set the delegate after Construction
    void delegate(const boost::weak_ptr<Task> task) {
      std::cout << "Callback:: void delegate(const boost::weak_ptr<Task> task) " << std::endl;
      this->m_delegate = task;
    }


    void delegateSomething() {
      std::cout << "Callback::delegateSomething()" << std::endl;
      boost::shared_ptr<Task> sharedDelegate = this->m_delegate.lock();
      std::cout << "sharedDelegate: " << sharedDelegate << std::endl;
      if (sharedDelegate) {
        // Use *shared_delegate
        std::cout << "Callback::delegateSomething() use delegate" << std::endl;
        sharedDelegate->delegateMethod();
      }
    }

    private:
     boost::weak_ptr<Task> m_delegate;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "main: Construct Callback" << std::endl;
  Callback callback;

  std::cout << "main: Construct Task" << std::endl;
  Task task(callback);

  std::cout << "main: Connect callback delegate" << std::endl;
  boost::shared_ptr<Task> sharedTask = boost::make_shared<Task>(task);
  boost::weak_ptr<Task> weakTask(sharedTask);
  callback.delegate(weakTask);
  callback.delegateSomething();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of this functionality has been included into the C++ standard. If you can't use such a recent version, then the boost libraries are very near identical, and you can replace `std::` with `boost::` here.

For creating both a `shared_ptr` or a `weak_ptr` from a raw pointer, you must derive from `enabled_shared_from_this`, for example:

```
class Foo : public std::enabled_shared_from_this<Foo> // C++11
{
};
...
Foo *ptr = ...;
std::shared_ptr<Foo> a = foo->shared_from_this(); // C++11
std::weak_ptr<Foo> b = foo->weak_from_this(); // C++17
```

The `enabled_shared_from_this` will add a little size to your type, but then so does `make_shared` with a type not using it, so if that is a concern, or often for simplicity, there is `unique_ptr` (C++11) that is more like a raw pointer.

It still doesn't normally make sense to try and make one from a stack allocated object, as the shared_ptr will not prevent it being deleted like normal local variables, and in fact could cause double deletion. You can do some tricks like give it a "no-op" deleter for the second problem.

In the case of `Foo *ptr` you also need to be sure that some other `shared_ptr` to it still exists, else the `ptr` may have been deleted already.

Comment: That's helpful but it doesn't answer the question.